# Absolutely/Conditional Convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

Is there an example of a power series that is conditionally convergent at one endpoint and absolutely cinvergent at another? Do such series exist at all?

Comment: @AnotherUser I have seen their discussion too. Unfortunately, they mainly discuss possibility of having absolute convergence at both endpoints. There are plenty examples of that to be true. Or absolutely convergent at one endpoint and divergent at other. But I have never seen an example of aforementioned case so far. Thank you!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the accepted answer addresses your question

Comment: absolute convergence at any point on the circle of convergence means absolute convergence everywhere on the circle convergence so there cannot be absolute convergence at one end and anything else (not absolute convergence) at the other